# How to use html from another file?

Tags: php, html

I have a html file which is just my footer. How can I use this in another file? Do I need to use php?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
<section>
<p>site content</p>
</section>

<?php footer html from a different file goes here ?>
```

Will this include the styling and javascript that is referenced in the head of the file i'm getting the html from?

Thanks!

Comment: `<?php include('footer.php);?>`

Comment: If `footer.php` doesn't have any php that needs executing you can use `<?php readfile('footer.php'); ?>`

Comment: @NickParsons is there any noticeable performance difference in doing this?

Comment: @treyBake not entirely sure as I'm not a PHP expert, but I would imagine it would as it wouldn't need to be processed by PHP on the server side

Comment: @NickParsons hmm.. might do some benchmarks and see what's what :)

Comment: @treyBake Okay, it would be intresting to see the outcome :)

Comment: @Masivuye Cokile Unfortunately this does not include the styling. Is there any way to include that?

Comment: @EdAT check the duplicate link above

Comment: @NickParsons you may add SSI as the third option to be compared

Comment: @NickParsons http://codepad.org/mlQGP9qz <-- did some testing - ignore errors outputted :)

Comment: @treyBake hm, intresting. Thanks for letting me know :D

Answer (score -1):

Now, when you visit index.html, you should be able to click the link tags.

**IN HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("header.html"); 
  $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<!--Remaining section-->
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**IN PHP**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<!--Remaining section-->
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure I see the JS or jQuery tag in the question ...

Comment: Is not it gonna be not SEO friendly ?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using PHP you can require you can find more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp).
If you don't want to use PHP you will have to use [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).
Example :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "yourHTMLFile.html",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
     $("body").html(data);
    }
});​
```

Comment: this requires use of jQuery - which not everyone wants to use

Comment: also this is really counter-intuitive - much better to simply use include in PHP -will execute a lot faster ...